# Get the id on modal when click on anchor tag for open modal using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal open on click anchor tag and passing the id value in input hidden field using javascript and value is show in this hidden field

```
    <a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>" 
id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>" class="btn-floating 
waves-effect waves-light yellow modal-trigger" title="Test"></a>
        <div id="modal2" class="modal">
             <form action="lst_applicant.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <input type="hidden" id="applicantid" name="applicantid" value="" />
                     <p>Applicant Information</p>
                     <?php  
                         $applicant_detail=mysql_query("select * from tbl_useraccount where id=".$applicantid); 
                     ?>
                 </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="submit" name='save' class="btn waves-effect waves-light right modal-close">Save</button>
                      </div>
                   </form> 
               </div>

    Here is the code of javascript passing the id value in input hidden field

        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".modal-trigger", function () {
            var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
            $(".modal-content #applicantid").val( myBookId );
          });
        </script>
```

Issue is that when I get id in hidden field but cannot get in php variable. how to get id on modal when opening a modal?

When I click on anchor tag for open a modal then on modal there is one input hidden field, in this hidden field show a id value of each anchor tag using javascript, I want that when this hidden field get id value so how to get in php variable? I am getting in php variable but it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Read my question again

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I didn't read the question clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve data like this, you just have to provide the details in the `anchor modal data`

`data-id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>"` and for name `data-name="<?php echo $CRow['name'];?>"` and so on

```js
$(document).on("click", ".modal-trigger", function () {
  var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var email = $(this).data('email');
  $(".modal-content #applicantid").val( myBookId );
  $("#appli_name").val(name);
  $("#appli_email").val(email);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-id="23" data-name="John" data-email="john@gmail.com" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light yellow modal-trigger" title="Test">Click</a>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <form>
  <div class="modal-content">
  <input type="text" id="applicantid" name="applicantid" value="" />
    <p>Applicant Information</p>
    <input type="text" id="appli_name"><br>
    <input type="text" id="appli_email">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" name='save' class="btn waves-effect waves-light right modal-close">Save</button>
  </div>
 </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: okay, understood. then this line `$applicant_detail=mysql_query("select * from tbl_useraccount where id=".$applicantid);` shouldn't be like `$applicant_detail=mysql_query("select * from tbl_useraccount where id='.$applicantid.'");`

Comment: you're welcome, so what is the reason you choose this one as the accepted answer? just curious... because it may be different like how you want to achieve user data from `id`

Comment: I got the point that where I add data-id and also I add name, email and etc.. as u said that already.. then popluate into modal using javascript that's why I choose this answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get details of that data only inside the modal, you can achieve everything before `anchor-tag` passing, like how you get `id`. And you can pass along the details of that data inside the `modal`

Example: `data-name="<?php echo $CRow['name']; ?>"` and in your javascript `var name=$(this).data('name');`

```
<a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>" id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>" data-name="<?php echo $CRow['name']; ?>" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light yellow modal-trigger" title="Test"></a>
```

Comment: I've checked, you want the `applicant-details` inside your modal right? then go for my suggestion if you like..hehe

Comment: you just have to populated applicant details like `name` `email` `etc` and defined in the `a-tag` data like `data-name` `data-email` and inside your javascript code, create a variable and assigned the data like `var name = $(this).data('name')` then passed that variable inside your modal