# Laravel Pass Old or value to modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, modal-dialog

Seems like Modal is not very easy to implement on large scales, I want to find an alternative way to pass values to the modal in order to display it properly.

In the blow example, I'm populating the "name" field from the dataTable itself, this works great but what if I want to pass for example

```
old('name') ?? $document->name
```

How would I be able to accomplish this on a large scale, say a 10+ fields entry?

**Button**

```
<a href="#"><i class="bx bxs-edit text-primary bx-sm edit" title="Edit Document"></i></a>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#indextable').DataTable();
    
    //Edit Record
    table.on('click', '.edit', function(){
       $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       if ($($tr).hasClass('child')){
           $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
       }
        //Config Table
        var data = table.row($tr).data();
        $('#name').val(data[1]);
        
        $('#editForm').attr('action', '/virtual/documents/'+data[0]);
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });
    
    $("#editForm").submit(function () {
        $(".submit").attr("disabled", true);
            return true;
    });
});

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    $('#editModal').modal('show');
@endif
</script>
```

Comment: look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077462/8826120

Comment: @Vpa wow seriously, that was amazingly easy to do!! Now its working exactly as I wanted, but I modified the solution different than the answer in the other stack, although using the concept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that made sense to do.

**Step 1)** In the button add a data-### and it must be before a title is specified.

```
<a href="#"><i class="bx bxs-edit text-primary bx-sm edit" data-name="{{old('name') ?? $document->name}} " title="Edit Document"></i></a>
```

**Step 2)** In the script, you can grab the data with example "$(this).data('name');"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    //Getting the datatable ready
    var table = $('#indextable').DataTable();
    //if the edit button is clicked
    table.on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var nameData = $(this).data('name');
        $("#name").val(nameData);
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });
});
//On error keep the modal open
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    $('#editModal').modal('show');
@endif
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to reflash the session, for example;

```
//On error keep the modal open
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    {{ Session::reflash()}}
    $('#editModal').modal('show');
@endif
```

Then you can use standard `old('value')` syntax in your modal view.